# Multiple definition error when compiling C++ code in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am stuck for hours on a problem that is probably very trivial.

This is a most basic use of classes.

Header file: person.h

```
class person
{
  protected:
    std::string _Name;
  public:
    void setName(std::string);
};
```

Implementation: person.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "person.h"

void person::setName(std::string name)
{
  _Name = name;
}
```

Driver: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.cpp"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Yes, it worked.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile this code in CodeBlocks (using GNU GCC), I get an error:

```
~\person.cpp|5|multiple definition of `person::setName(std::string)'|
~\person.cpp|5|first defined here|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I have a prototype in the header file and the body in the implementation file. Where is the multiple definition? It works if I add 'inline' before 'void' in person.cpp, but why should I in this case?

Furthermore, when compiling this same exact code in cmd as "g++ main.cpp -o main.exe", it works perfectly (without inline)!

Comment: Don't include cpp files. Link them. That aside, your header should have an include guard.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to include `*.cpp` file in main.cpp. You need to include `*.h` file.

In short - `*.cpp` files contains implementation and compiled by the compiler. `*.h` files contains definitions and can be included from the `*.cpp` files. When you include `*.cpp` file, you get multiple definitions of the same object.

Also, you need to add include guard

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER
... code of your header file ...
#endif
```

or just add

```
#pragma once
```

if your compiler supports it.

Comment: #pragma once is not standard.

Comment: It's ubiquitous. This directive supported by VC++, GCC, Clang and Digital Mars.

Comment: Thank you! Changing line 2 of main.cpp from #include "person.cpp" to #include "person.h" made it work. But now I'm a bit confused. I include the header file in main.cpp. The header file makes no reference (that I can see) to the .cpp file that implements the declarations in the header file. Why don't I get an error? Is that something that's done behind the scenes?

Comment: @user1960469 The compiler compiles two separate translation units - main.cpp and person.cpp. The first contains the definition of the function `main` and the second contains the definition of `setName`. In your particular example, it doesn't really matter that main.cpp doesn't directly include the implementation of `person`, because you're not using it. An optimizing compiler will simply ignore the contents of person.h. However, if you were actually using that code, then the linker would combine the outputs of the two translation units, so that the definition is available to your final binary.

Answer (score 3):

had this happen today.

when adding a file in codeblocks using file - new etc there is a screen which asks if you want to include the file in debug and release versions.  you innocently answer yes by ticking the boxes.  the result is the file is automatically included and when you explicitly include it yourself you end up duplicating.  so, dont tick those boxes.

cheers
podge

Answer (score 0):

You can include a .cpp file inside another .cpp in codeblocks. But dont add it to the project you have created. If the file is included in project, code blocks will try to compile it like this:

g++ main.cpp -o main.o

g++ person.cpp -o person.o

and then create the final output file using the two .o files. Since main.cpp includes func.cpp, you will encounter the multiple declaration error.

Now, if you keep only the main.cpp file in the project, only that will be compiled and you will not get the same error.